# How to Route Multiple Pages to 'Edit' a Users Account Information (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rest, model

I currently have a Ruby on Rails application with a typical User model. I would like to allow users to edit their own account information, and change their email or password. However, I would like to have the corresponding forms for this on two different pages.

There is a `users_controller.rb` which already has a `show`, `new`, `create`, and `edit` path. The problem is that using the `edit` path to `update` the User database would require all forms to be on the same page, which is inconvenient for users who only wish to update their email or password, and not both. Essentially, I need that `edit` path to be available on multiple pages.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not possible.** Only one action per named route.

You could use one named route *plus an extra parameter* to tell the controller which form (or parts of a form) to render:

```
named route                                  path
edit_user_path(@user, :form => "info")       mysite.com/users/1/edit?form=info
edit_user_path(@user, :form => "acct")       mysite.com/users/1/edit?form=acct
edit_user_path(@user)                        mysite.com/users/1/edit
```

Then read this parameter and switch between templates depending on the value. No parameter will render the default view containing the full form:

```
def edit
  # ...
  case params[:form]
  when "info"
    render :template => "info_only"
  when "acct"
    render :template => "name_and_password"
  else
    render :action => :edit
  end
end
```

I assume this is just for UX and not for security. All of these separate forms will PUT to the same update action, meaning all attributes accessible in one form (eg. password) will be accessible in another form.

Comment: I'm a bit new to rails. How do I route this? I understand what you're saying, in terms of splitting the form into two templates, and calling those templates in the controller according to the parameter, but I'm assuming I have to 'match' the named routes to the controller somehow?

Comment: I'm using the `edit_user` named route provided by `resources :users`. [Query strings](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#the-query-string) work with Rails' default routes, including resourceful routes. No custom routing required.

Comment: Said simply, leave your routes file alone.

Comment: I have my controller set as

`  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
   case params[:form]
   when "Email"
     render 'email'
   when "Password"
     render 'password'
   else
     render :action => :edit
   end
 end`

and I have two pages with forms on them: `email.html.haml` and `password.html.haml`. There also a default `edit.html.haml`. My users resource is called in the `routes.rb`. When I visit the paths you mentioned, though, the new routes do work, but they still render the default edit template...I tried this with the `:template => "email"` as well.

Comment: `"email" != "Email"`. Those `when` clauses are case-sensitive.

Comment: Yep, the noob has figured it out! This solution worked completely :)

Answer (score 1):

Split the form up into separate `.html.erb` files (like `email.html.erb` and `password.html.erb`) and in your controller write something like:

```
def edit
  ...
  if params[:email]
    render 'email'
  end
  if params[:password]
    render 'password'
  end
end
```

Obviously the conditions can be whatever you want.